# Connect to MSSQL on remote, with windows authentication, JAVA

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I need to connect to remote ms sql.I have the windows server login information to connect. And that login user can connect to MSSQL server. (I mean I can connect to MSSQL server via Windows Authentication with that user)

I want to do that with Java code. I tried to connect by using jdbc driver, but I couldn't. How can I connect to MSSQL server remotely, with windows user which have right to connect MSSQL 2008 R2.

```
String connectionurl = "jdbc:sqlserver://remoteIP:port;databaseName=databasename;intergratedsecurity=true";
```

and even i tried with username password through which i can connect to remote windows server.

```
String connectionurl = "jdbc:sqlserver://remoteIP:port;databaseName=databasename;username=ab;password=bc";
```

error:

> Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:916ac72a-9c78-45f9-bc61-680793d1fea7
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)

Comment: The JDBC sqlServer username for sql authentication mode is just `user` - [reference MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342339(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: The first URL works for me. It's a bit tricky to put the correct version of `sqljdbc_auth.dll` into the correct directory though.

Comment: Hi stuartLC, still am getting same error String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://remoteIP:port;databaseName=databasename;user=username;password=password";

Answer (score 0):

Is it simply a typo?

```
intergratedsecurity=true
```

should be

```
integratedSecurity=true
```

Windows auth means that SQL Server uses the Windows login token. Because of this typo, it expects a username and password whcih you don't have. Hence the error message `Login failed for user ''.`

Comment: I have username and password to connect to remote server, even i use that it throws same error Login failed for user 'username'.

Comment: As windows or SQL login?

Comment: if i use integratedsecurity=true then it takes my local windows username.Login failed for user 'GLOBAL\_knp'

Comment: I have username and password for windows remote server. sql server uses windows authentication, for sql server i dont have username and password.

Comment: No i dont have.But i have separate credentials through which i can connect to windows server there by to sql by windows authentication

Comment: so, what *is* the problem? GLOBAL_knp does not have access as a Windows user to SQL Server. Add permissions or use your separate credentials.